# open image in fullscreen when it get clicked from grid view (fragments with sliding menu )

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i am developing my first app and so far i am successful to get images from sd card and to display them in gridview. but its not showing me in full screen when i am clicking on image.
i am working with the  fragments sliding menu. my app is getting force close whenever i tries to click on image.

blow is my xml and java files.

**GridViewactivity.java**

```
package com.Adz.mediaplus;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridViewActivity extends Fragment {

    private Utils utils;
    private ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
    private GridView gridView;
    private int columnWidth;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_grid_view,
                container, false);
        // Gridview adapter
        adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(getActivity(), imagePaths,
                columnWidth);

        // setting grid view adapter
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        utils = new Utils(getActivity());

        // Initilizing Grid View
        InitilizeGridLayout();

        // loading all image paths from SD card
        imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();

    }

    private void InitilizeGridLayout() {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
                (int) padding);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
    }

}
```

GridViewAdepter.java

```
package com.Adz.mediaplus;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int imageWidth;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
            int imageWidth) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._filePaths = filePaths;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this._filePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // get screen dimensions
        Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
                imageWidth);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
                imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        // image view click listener
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

        return imageView;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        int _postion;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this._postion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", _postion);
            _activity.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Resizing image size
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
        try {

            File f = new File(filePath);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**FullScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.Adz.mediaplus;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Fragment {

    private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);

        utils = new Utils(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        Intent i = super.getActivity().getIntent(); 
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(getActivity(),
                utils.getFilePaths());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

**FullScreenImageAdepter.java**

```
package com.Adz.mediaplus;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;
        Button btnClose;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // close button click event
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _activity.finish();
            }
        }); 

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

}
```

**activity_fullscreen_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_fullscreen_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.Adz.mediaplus.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
   01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ResourceType(9872): No known package when getting value for resource number 0xffffffff
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872): Unable to find resource: -1
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:722)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1909)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1834)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ResourceType(9872): No known package when getting value for resource number 0xffffffff
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872): Unable to find resource: -1
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/ImageView(9872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 22:03:46.443: W/Trace(9872): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-12 22:03:47.723: W/Trace(9872): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-12 22:03:47.723: W/Trace(9872): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-12 22:03:47.723: D/AndroidRuntime(9872): Shutting down VM
01-12 22:03:47.723: W/dalvikvm(9872): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5dd2908)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.Adz.mediaplus/com.Adz.mediaplus.FullScreenViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at com.Adz.mediaplus.GridViewImageAdapter$OnImageClickListener.onClick(GridViewImageAdapter.java:87)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-12 22:03:47.723: E/AndroidRuntime(9872):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post log from logcat?

Comment: "ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.Adz.mediaplus/com.Adz.mediaplus.FullScreenViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations:

1. Don't call end your fragment names with Activity. End them with Fragment. They are not activities, they are Fragments. It will only add confusion.
2. You haven't declared FullScreenViewActivity in your manifest.
3. The crash happens because of this: `_activity.startActivity(i);`

See #2.

1. Don't use "_" for member variables. The Android (albeit not necessarily better) convention is to use "m". So mActivity, mPosition, etc. Unless it's a local variable, in which case no prefix is needed (position, activity, etc.).
2. You are re-creating your adapter `onStart()`, this is somewhat inefficient, you would probably want to create it only once and do a `notifyDataSetChanged()` for any other case.

**UPDATE**:

I am short on time because I have to leave, but the idea behind notifyDataSetChanged would be…

```
void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   if ( mAdapter == null ) {
      mAdapter = new YourAdapter(); // blah blah blah
      mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      ///etc.
   } else {
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: i have changed all the things that you have mentioned .
1. changing variables
2. adding in menifest
 bt dont know how to do niotifyDataSetChanged()  in this

Comment: thank you sir ,Got image clicking working buy changing Extend fragment to activity . but now i am no more able to get that central sliding menu within fullScreenActivitiy.  any idea how to fix??